# Android: Web View With Internet Connection Notificatification

Tags: android, eclipse

Can help me about web view with Notofication Internet Connetion..

I want to show notification if no connection available,like this image.

```
if connection is good 
      then show web view 
 else show the notification
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if there is a network connection available using the following code.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to check internet connection.If the response is false,you can show "no internet connection message"

```
public Boolean CheckNetworkConnection(Context con) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
        NetworkInfo wifiInfo, mobileInfo;
        Boolean result = false;
        try {
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) con
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            wifiInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            mobileInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            if (wifiInfo.isConnected() || mobileInfo.isConnected())
                result = true;
            else
                result = false;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return result;
    }
```